# Characterization of Epis in Category of Quasi-projective varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If we are in the category of [quasiprojective varieties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiprojective_variety) over an algebraically closed field $k$, where the arrows are regular continuous maps (under the Zariski topology), what properties will the epi arrows possess? I'm particularly interested if the image of an epi is dense in the target space. If not, is there an easy counterexample?

EDIT: I have little background in scheme theory and am currently taking a first course in Algebraic Geometry using Hartshorne. My inquiry is concerning the proof of Thm 4.4 (p25) which says that given varieties $X$ and $Y$, $U$ open in $X$, then the injective k-algebra homomorphism $\theta:A(Y)\to \mathcal{O}(U)$ induces $ \phi: U\to Y $ which gives a dominant rational map $X \dashrightarrow  Y$. I'm attempting to see that im$ \phi$ is dense. My intuition lead me to the above query.

Comment: Are you working over an algebraically closed field?

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/56564

Comment: You don't have to consider epis in order to understand the proof in Hartshorne.

Comment: I don't see where the dominance is shown in Hartshorne. I was thinking that since $\mathcal{O}$ is faithful and monos are reflected, $\phi$ is epi. I can't come up with an epi arrow that is not dense. So I was wondering if its right. My professor gave some convoluted argument amounting to passing to several different factor rings and making some argument about its spectrum. So I was wondering why it should be so convoluted...

Comment: Wait, $\mathcal{O}$ is not faithful, is it?, since any projective variety would have iso ring of regular functions, ie equal to the base field.